# Write JSON in developer-friendly fashion in shell script arguments

Tags: shell, pretty-print, heredoc

I have a shellscript where I need to pass JSON as a function argument

I'd like to write developer-friendly indented code instead of writing hard to maintain one-line arguments, or multiple line arguments with escaped newlines and quotes

What I'm starting with

```
kubectl patch deployment ${APP_NAME} \
      --patch="{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"friendly_tag\":\"${FRIENDLY_TAG}\",\"deployed_by\":\"${DEPLOYED_BY}\"}}}}}" \
```

What I'd like to end with (the example below obviously won't work in the shell)

```
kubectl patch deployment ${APP_NAME} \
      --patch={ 
         "spec": {
              "template": {
                  "metadata": {
                      "annotations": {
                          "friendly_tag": "${FRIENDLY_TAG}",
                          "deployed_by": "${DEPLOYED_BY}"
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Would there be a way to rpeserve such a syntax without using additional variables ? Otherwise how can I write my shellscripts while still preserving developer friendliness ?

I know I could use heredocs, but I'm not so sure I could use them if I have 2 JSON arguments to pass to my function (other that putting my heredoc in variables and just passing them as arguments)

Also, in this case the json quotes need escaping, so I'm not sure heredocs would be convenient at all.

EDIT: The heredoc syntax I'm talking about (that forces you to have an unindented `JSON` closing tag)

```
PATCH=$(jq -R -s --raw-output '.' <<-JSON
        {
          "spec": {
            "template": {
              "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
                  "friendly_tag": "${FRIENDLY_TAG}",
                  "deployed_by": "${DEPLOYED_BY}"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
JSON
    )
    kubectl patch deployment ${APP_NAME} \
      --patch="${PATCH}" \
      --context ${KUBECTL_CONTEXT} \
      -n ${ENVIRONMENT}
```

Comment: The heredoc approach is also insecure; it doesn't escape your data to make it valid JSON if it isn't already. And in general, I'd advise you to worry, when writing shell, **much** more about correctness and security than developer-friendliness.

Comment: (if you run your code through http://shellcheck.net/ you'll see other bugs, like `${APP_NAME}` not being guaranteed to expand to exactly one word; that's another case where shell is _inherently_ human-unfriendly because of bad design decisions made back in the 1970s, and it's necessary to inject a certain amount of ceremony -- like quoting `"${APP_NAME}"` or `"$APP_NAME"` -- to ensure that your code can't do incorrect things when run).

Comment: ...in general, if your first priority is making code _look_ pretty, I strongly urge you to choose a different language; ideally something with macros so you can write code that munges the code that people write into the form you need it to be. If you're going to be writing tools to be used from shell, having the users of those tools need to know what they're doing to avoid security and correctness bugs is _completely_ unavoidable. (If it helps to make an appeal-from-authority argument, [I can try to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/topusers)).

Answer (score 2):

Before you can get into friendliness, there are larger concerns regarding correctness. To address them, consider:

```
export FRIENDLY_TAG DEPLOYED_BY # variables need to be in the environment

kubectl patch deployment "${APP_NAME}" \
  --patch="$(jq -n '
    { 
      "spec": {
        "template": {
          "metadata": {
            "annotations": {
              "friendly_tag": env.FRIENDLY_TAG,
              "deployed_by": env.DEPLOYED_BY
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }')"
```

This is about as friendly as you can be without compromising correctness.

- Use of single quotes around the jq expression ensures that there aren't any extra backslashes needed within that expression.
- Use of the jq `env` reference to refer to environment variables avoids the ceremony of using `--arg` to pass arguments into jq.
- A tag (or deployed_by value) with literal quotes, tabs, newlines, backslashes, or other jq syntax will be correctly escaped instead of being able to inject arbitrary JSON content into the output document (or, if taking place by mistake rather than malicious activity -- rather than making that output no longer valid JSON).

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and the warnings! much appreciated.

Comment: What if `jq` return error due to misspell or typo? Guess it's safer to create var first and check that it's correct and than do the patch.

Comment: Could you explain how to work with curl data-binary ? in my previous scripts I used scripts like `curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
      --data-binary @- << JSON ${SLACK_WEBHOOK}
{...} 
JSON`. I'm not sure if I can use jq in the same way there... (sorry if it becomes off-topic)

Comment: @Ivan, misspell or typo _where_? In the code? That's what testing is for. It won't care about problems with the data; any data that's valid in an environment variable can be converted to a JSON string, as can some values that aren't (NULs aren't possible in environment variables, but can be converted into `\u0000` in a JSON string).

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris, assuming you have a shell with ksh93 extensions (also present in bash and zsh), `--data-binary @- < <(jq -n '...')`; whereas if you're guaranteed only POSIX compliance, `jq -n '...' | curl ... --data-binary @-`. One can also use `--data-binary @- <<EOF`, then a line containing `$(jq -n '`, your JQ expression, a line with `')`, then a line with `EOF` (replace the sigil as you see fit).